# Append an element before 1st key inside .map() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to recreate whatsapp/telegram-like timeline where messages divided by days.
For rendering messages in React I use Object.key(messages).map function.

```
Object.keys(this.messages).map(e => {
    return <div key={i++}>
              { this.messages[e] }
```

How to add e.g. 'today' between the last yesterday and first today messages?

Comment: What is example `message` structure?

Comment: Thank you for the question! Just regular object { body: 'text', time: 'unix timestamp' }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would group all messages into separate arrays, each for each day that occurs. In order to do that, create an object - its keys will be unique days and its values - messages from these days.

```js
// object similar to your 'messages' state
const messages = {
  message1: {
    body: "one day before message",
    time: 1534433188201
  },
  message2: {
    body: "newest message",
    time: 1534519588201
  },
  message3: {
    body: "2 days before newest message",
    time: 1534346788201
  },
  message4: {
    body: "also 2 days before newest message",
    time: 1534346788250
  }
};
// creating array from your object
const messagesArray = Object.keys(messages).map(m => messages[m]);
// sorting array - oldest to newest
const latestMessages = messagesArray.sort((a, b) => a.time > b.time);
// grouping by date - create an object, each key is a different date and value is an array of messages from that day
const groupedByDate = {};
latestMessages.forEach(message => {
  const date = new Date(message.time);
  const day = date.getDate();
  const month = date.getMonth();
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  // this will create 'date_17-7-2018' format as an example - you can do whatever you want/need here
  const key = `date_${day}-${month}-${year}`;
  // push message to existing key or create new array containing this message
  if(groupedByDate[key]) {
    groupedByDate[key].push(message);
  } else {
    groupedByDate[key] = [message];
  }
});
console.log(groupedByDate);
```

The rendering part seems easy now - here's an example how i would approach this:

Map over `Object.keys(groupedByDate)` and for each key return `div` or `span` with a `className="date-label"`(example). If a day extracted from this key is equal to `(new Date()).getDate()` - render "today", if it's `(new Date()).getDate() - 1` - render "yesterday", otherwise render "X days ago". Now inside this `map` loop you also need to `map` over `groupedByDate[key]` (array of messages from this day) and render messages.

Comment: Actually sorting and filtering kind of things is fully covered by my Firebase backend. I just was asking about simply adding dates between messages. Please take a look https://imgur.com/GM317lI. Thank for that momentjs library anyway!

Comment: The tricky part here is that you need to add date tag only between messages which belong to different dates. Messages within a day must not be divided. Hence we need to append an element before the first message of the day.

Comment: I wouldn't push something that isn't a message into `messages` array. I would create an object with each day as keys, and its values would be arrays of messages from these days. See updated answer :) this is it - without using momentjs. But for a project like this I highly recommend it. Your screen was very helpful to understand the problem, you should've included it in your question :)

Comment: That's just brilliant - exactly what I wanted to learn! That's pretty darn smart approach, thank you for the whole working snippets! Already on my way to implement your idea! Sorry for confusing beginning!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Object.keys(this.messages).map(message => {
      const date = new Date();
      date.setHours(0,0,0,0);  // will set to midnight
      const today = Math.round(date.getTime() / 1000);
      const timeDifference = this.state.time - today;
      const isInRange = timeDifference >= 0 && timeDifference <=86400;
      if (isInRange && !this.state.labelAlreadyPresent) {
        this.setState({ showLabel: true, labelAlreadyPresent: true });
      } else if(!isInRange) {
         this.setState({ labelAlreadyPresent: false, showLabel: true });
      } else {
         this.setState({ showLabel: false });
      }

      return (
         <div key={message.time}>
           {this.state.showLabel && <label> Today </label>}
           { message.body }
         </div>
       );
```

so basically you first get today's date and set it to midnight. then you get the unix timestamp in seconds. After that you compare the timestamp with the timestamp you received in response and if its within the range of 0 to 86400(equal to 1 day) then you show the Today label.

In the initial state make `labelAlreadyPresent` and `showLabel` as false

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That's one quite interesting approach! What about simultaneously adding previous dates as well? Please see https://imgur.com/GM317lI

Comment: Please note that we need to append an element just before the first message of the day. Other messages within the day should not be affected and go in a single block.